# How can I use url_for / polymorphic_url from an ActiveJob job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have a notification service that I'm invoking from inside an ActiveJob job (using delayed_job backend). The subject of each notification is a model instance and could be any of several different classes.  For recipient convenience, I need to include a link to the view for that object.

This doesn't work, because url_for is not a method available in the job context:

```
class NotificationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(object, message)
    NotificationService.send(url_for(object), message)
  end
end
```

In a previous and more limited version of this code, I used `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.model_name_url(object)`, but that's model-specific. And it seems that `Rails.application.routes.url_for` wants a controller/action specification, not a model.

In mailers I can use `url_for(object)` and it does the right thing, whatever the model class. So how might I access the polymorphic url helpers in a job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit more thinking (and reading through the Rails source) I came up with a solution. I created an app-specific base class in `app/jobs/application_job.rb` to inherit jobs from:

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  protected
  def default_url_options
    Rails.application.config.active_job.default_url_options
  end
end
```

added the necessary to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_job.default_url_options = { host: "example.com" }
```

and changed my original class thus:

```
class NotificationJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(object, message)
    NotificationService.send(url_for(object), message)
  end
end
```

I was surprised to find that the behaviour of `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for` is so different as an included instance method rather than as the singleton, but inspection of source confirmed it.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: see @lucas-nelson answer for rails 4.2+

Answer (score 8):

@inopinatus's answer is great, but I was tripped up in Rails 4 with the configuration.

```
config.active_job.default_url_options = { host: "example.com" }
```

Caused "NoMethodError: undefined method `default_url_options=' for ActiveJob::Base:Class" when initialising the first ActiveJob.

The [Rails 4 configuration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/configuring.html#custom-configuration) describes using `config.x…` for custom properties. I needed to make the following adjustments:

```
def default_url_options
  Rails.configuration.x.application_job.default_url_options
end
```

and

```
config.x.application_job.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I should've said I was using Rails 5. NB: the documentation URL for rails 4 has changed, you now want http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/configuring.html#custom-configuration.